# LINQ Equivalent of "select *, count()"

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

I have two table A , B on SQL Server like bellow:

Columns of A: id1, id2, col_1, ... , col_100

Columns of B: id1, id2, ... (some columns)

I want to write the equivalent of below SQL query in the C# Linq:

```sql
select *, (select count(*) from B where A.id1 = B.id1 and A.id2 = b.id2)  from  A
```

I know that this can be done like below:

```cs
var lst = db.TableA.Select(a => new {
    id1 = a.id1,
    id2 = a.id2,
    col_1 = a.col_1,
    ...
    ,
    col_100 = a.col_100,
    count = db.TableB.Where(b => b.id1 = a.id1 && b.id2 == a.id2).Count()
});
```

But in this format I have to mention all the columns of the table A, While I just want to add just one new column to the existing columns of the table A, Something like this: `select *, count()`

Can you help me?

Comment: Does this work? `.Select(a => new { a, count = db.TableB.Count(b => b.id1 == a.id1 && b.id2 == a.id2) })`

Comment: `db.TableA.Select(a => new { A = a, Count = db.TableB.Where(...).Count()})`

Comment: @RichardDeeming No, It has a compiled error.

Comment: @class1234 And the error message is?

Comment: @KieranDevlin I want the new column (Count) to be added to at same level of A columns. not outside of A object.

Comment: And what type of object do you expect to be returned from the query and what will you do with it?

Comment: @RichardDeeming please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70068681/linq-equivalent-of-select-count/70087237#comment123906920_70087237

Comment: @KieranDevlin please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70068681/linq-equivalent-of-select-count/70087237#comment123906920_70087237

Comment: @class1234 If you want someone to help you fix an error, then you need to tell us what the error is. A link to a comment where you don't provide any details of the error does not help.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
var result = dbContext.TableA.Select(a => new
{
    A = a,
    Count = dbContext.TableB.Where(b => b.id1 = a.id1 && b.id2 == a.id2)
                            .Count(),
});
```

So you select the complete row from tableA in property A, and you put the number of corresponding items in tableB in property Count

Comment: No. As I said I want the result to be filled by only columns (A.id1, A.id2, A.col_1, ..., A.col_100, Count). but in your solution, the result filled with "property A" and "Count column".

Comment: Yes I know, and this does really make a big difference for you?